# O que signifca o * das palavras reservadas sync*, async*, yield*?

Tags: flutter, dart

O que signifca o * das palavras reservadas sync*, async*, yield*? Qual a diferença entre elas e seu similares sync, async e yield?

Comment: Se bem entendi, uma função async retorna um Future (uma tarefa postergada), enquanto uma função async* é uma geradora de várias tarefas postergadas. Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397023/whats-the-difference-between-async-and-async-in-dart (última resposta).

Comment: @epx Correto 'várias tarefas' na verdade são ou é as `Streams`, que podem utilizadas com `yield / yield*.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa palavras são chamada de "Star-keywords" e são usadas em funções de gerador.

**Explicando melhor**

São usadas em funções que vão retornar dados *on-demand*, ou seja, apenas quando realmente formos fazer uso dos dados que serão retornados. 
 Isso serve tanto para funções síncronas (sync*) quanto para as assíncronas (async*).

**Exemplo**

*Vou dar um exemplo usando um `Interable<int>` apenas para o entendimento do **

```
void main() {
  print('create iterator');
  Iterable<int> numbers = getNumbers(3);
  print('starting to iterate...');
  for (int val in numbers) {
    print('$val');
  }
  print('end of main');
}

Iterable<int> getNumbers(int number) sync* {
  print('generator started');
  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
  print('generator ended');
}
```

Rode esse programa no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) e veja o seguinte resultado:

> ```
> create iterator
> starting to iterate...
> generator started
> 0
> 1
> 2
> generator ended
> end of main
> ```

Como pode ser visto no log de retorno, o gerador apenas começou quando a variável `numbers` foi realmente utilizada, ou seja, os valores retornados pelo método `getNumbers` apenas foram gerados no momento em que foram necessários.

Fontes:

- [What are sync*, async*, yield and yield* in Dart?](https://medium.com/@jelenaaa.lecic/what-are-sync-async-yield-and-yield-in-dart-defe57d06381) *(Em inglês)*
- [Funções de Gerador - Flutter em Foco](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TF-TBsgIErY) *(Em inglês)*